# Ubuntu Studio and KX Studio distros

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I am interested in installing a pro-audio Linux distro. I do hesitate between Ubuntu Studio and KX Studio (Tango Studio and ArtistX could also be an option).

I would like to know what are the main differences between Ubuntu and KX Studio? Moreover, would there be any advantage to add XK packages to Ubuntu Studio?

Answer (score 2):

> **Ubuntu Studio** is Linux-based operating system designed as a free, open, and powerful platform for creative people to create their art.
>
> Ubuntu Studio is also Free and Open Source Software (FOSS). Ubuntu
>   Studio free to download and use. You can get the source code, study it
>   and modify it. You can redistribute Ubuntu Studio and can even
>   redistribute your modified version. Read more about these freedoms at
>   GNU.org’s Free Software page.
>
> As an officially recognized derivative of Ubuntu, Ubuntu Studio is
>   supported by Canonical Ltd. and an amazing and continually increasing
>   community.
>
> Ubuntu Studio is released every six months, but a long term release
>   (LTS) version is released only every 2 years.
>
> Contents:
>
> - Audio
> - Graphics
> - Video
> - Photography
> - Publishing<sup>1</sup>
>
> **KXStudio** is a collection of applications, artwork and plugins, targeted at audio and video production. KXStudio is also a Linux
>   Distribution, currently based on Ubuntu 12.04. Although focused on
>   GNU/Linux, some of our applications work in other Operating Systems.
>
> The KXStudio project is divided into 4 categories:
>
> - Applications
> - Artwork
> - Plugins
> - Repositories (it uses Ubuntu repositories (PPAs))<sup>2</sup>

Based on the information above, I would recommend that you go with Ubuntu Studio.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/)</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[KXStudio](http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/)</sup>